# How to restore a postgres backup - ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a postgres backup from a system that is no longer provisioned, and I'm getting a range of errors, depending on what I try.

- I have only the backups, no original servers to refer to
- I've successfully restored from these production backups in the past, but have messed with my local environment since last success (eg reinstalled postgres via Homebrew)
- I believe that a former colleague (no longer available) has successfully restored this particular backup
- I've encountered the same error when:

  - trying the backup using postgresql@9.4
  - trying a previous known-good version of the database (using postgres 11)

(I've read related/suggested questions, and they don't seem relevant)

The backup was created on using the following command (in a bash script):

```
pg_dump --schema=public -Fc
```

And the command used to restore the script (which is echo'd as help text by backup script) is:

```bash
dropdb ${PGDATABASE}
createdb ${PGDATABASE}
time pg_restore \
    -j4 \
    -d ${PGDATABASE} \
    --create \
    --no-privileges \
    --no-owner \
    --clean \
    --if-exists \
    --exit-on-error \
    "${dirname}/${filename}"
```

When I run the restore command locally, I get the following:

```
time pg_restore -j4 -d ${PGDATABASE} --create --no-privileges --no-owner --clean --if-exists --exit-on-error ../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.pg_dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4954; 1262 962277 DATABASE mydb mydb
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
    Command was: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.019s
sys    0m0.012s
```

Previously, I've only ever had 'out of disk space errors' after minutes of operation, but as you can see from the `time` output, this error occurs almost immediately!

The backup is created with compression `-Fc` , and I'm able to de-compress the backup to plaintext using `pg_restore backup.pg_dump > backup.sql`, but I'm unable to find any commands in there related to `DROP DATABASE` :/

```
-- Dumped from database version 9.6.11
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.3 (Ubuntu 11.3-1.pgdg14.04+1)
```

I see that the DB was originally dumped from `9.6.11` but I'm reasonably sure that I previously restored successfully with PG 10...

I have tried various things, like:

```
time pg_restore -d ${PGDATABASE} --no-privileges --no-owner --exit-on-error ../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.pg_dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 7; 2615 1033373 SCHEMA public mydb
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;

ptim:dropdb mydb; createdb mydb
ptim:directory ptim$ dropdb mydb

ptim:directory ptim$ time pg_restore -d ${PGDATABASE} --create --no-privileges --no-owner --exit-on-error ../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.pg_dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist

# guess I misunderstood the create flag!

ptim:directory ptim$ dropdb mydb; createdb mydb
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "mydb" does not exist

ptim:directory ptim$ time pg_restore -d ${PGDATABASE} --create --no-privileges --no-owner --exit-on-error ../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.pg_dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4954; 1262 962277 DATABASE mydb mydb
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  database "mydb" already exists
    Command was: CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

I also tried unsuccessfully to restore from the plaintext dump:

```
psql -U ptim -d mydb -1 -f ../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.sql

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config
------------

(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.sql:23: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
psql:../backups/backup__2019-09-03_16-00-19.sql:26: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

# snip... repeated, and varied errors follow
```

Any suggestions?!

Comment: If you use `--create` you need to connect to a _different_ database, e.g. `postgres` or `template1` `pg_restore -j4 -d postgres ... `

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! Solved! (TLDR; I dropped the `--create` option) Your comment led me to this explanation of `--create`: [why-pg-restore-ignores-create...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82161/why-pg-restore-ignores-create-error-failed-fatal-database-new-db-does-n) - thanks again! Would you like to add an answer, or shall I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from @a_horse_with_no_name, I learned:

> `-C`, `--create` Create the database before restoring into it. If `--clean` is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.
>
> When this option is used, the database named with `-d` is used only to issue the initial `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE` commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

(Further explained at [dba.stackexchange: why pg_restore ignores --create](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82161/why-pg-restore-ignores-create-error-failed-fatal-database-new-db-does-n). Note that `--create` has further, unrelated effects in newer versions of [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html))

My solution was to remove the `--create` param:

```
dropdb ${PGDATABASE}
createdb ${PGDATABASE}
time pg_restore \
    -j4 \
    -d ${PGDATABASE} \
    --no-privileges \
    --no-owner \
    --clean \
    --if-exists \
    --exit-on-error \
    backup.pg_dump
```

Comment: I try to do similar thing and follow official document to use --create which gives me lots of error and worries me. By removing --create and only use --clean, it seems to be normal.

Comment: Removing `--create` worked for me, thanks for saving my day. It worked in Postgres 11 (as compared to Postgres 13 which added the `--force` in `dropdb` command)

Comment: This isn't a solution, you just stopped doing the thing that was raising errors. Note the docs you quoted say _"If --clean is also specified, drop and recreate the target database **before connecting** to it"_.  This means that your version of Postgres is misbehaving, because that's not what it's doing and instead you're working around it by dropping/creating the DB manually.  This is an issue with --clear for PG < 12 as noted in the stackexchange link you provided.

Comment: Tx for the comment @Madbreaks - I can't see any reference to a bug in the docs (I'd expect a "Note:" callout under the relevant flag). AFAICT, I was misusing the `--create` flag in conjunction with `-d` and `--clean`. What I intended was accomplished by omitting `--create`.